# OpenVPN struggling

Tags: 12.04, networking, openvpn

I've got some problems with my OpenVPN setup.

**The Setup:**
-> Ubuntu Server 12.04
-> Two active NIC's: eth0 (default): 192.168.1.0/24
eth1: x.x.x.x (external ip)

I've managed to get the routing to work so i can connect to the outside world with the eth1 NIC.

```
holmen@filserver:~$ ping -I eth1 -c 3 www.linuxquestions.org
PING www.linuxquestions.org (75.126.162.205) from 192.168.1.2 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.linuxquestions.org (75.126.162.205): icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=133 ms
64 bytes from www.linuxquestions.org (75.126.162.205): icmp_req=2 ttl=50 time=133 ms
64 bytes from www.linuxquestions.org (75.126.162.205): icmp_req=3 ttl=50 time=133 ms

--- www.linuxquestions.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 133.281/133.336/133.379/0.423 ms
One curious thing is that the "from ip #". It says "from 192.168.1.2 eth1" but that ip is the servers ip on the eth0 iface.
```

**Netstat:**

```
holmen@filserver:~$ netstat -anr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
x.x.x.x     0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

**But here comes the real problem:**
When setting up openvpn with the option "local x.x.x.x (eth1 ext ip)" it still tunnels the eth0 interface. And i cant understand why.

**OpenVPN settings:**

```
client

dev tap

proto udp

local x.x.x.x

remote openvpn.anonine.net 1194
remote openvpn.anonine.net 1195
remote openvpn-2.anonine.net 1196
remote openvpn-2.anonine.net 1197
remote openvpn-3.anonine.net 1198
remote openvpn-3.anonine.net 1199
remote openvpn-4.anonine.net 1200
remote openvpn-4.anonine.net 1201

remote-random

resolv-retry infinite

auth-user-pass

persist-key
persist-tun

ca anonine.ca.crt

ns-cert-type server

comp-lzo

reneg-sec 0

verb 3
```

**Netstat (tunnel active):**

```
holmen@filserver:~$ netstat -anr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         46.246.20.129   128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tap0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
x.x.x.x         0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
46.246.20.128   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U         0 0          0 tap0
80.67.8.222     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
128.0.0.0       46.246.20.129   128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tap0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this with two main steps:

1. Choose a service provider that uses TUN interface.
2. A little bit more table routing

**The Table routing**

I've read the most useful howto over at [http://lartc.org/howto/](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) and followed the provided steps there.

My setup is now two physical nic (eth0 and eth1) divided over three tables (main, T1 and T2).
T1(eth1) routes the default stuff (apache2, ssh etc.) and T2(eth0) is just for rtorrent connections.

It works like a charm. So if you have the same issue read up over at lartc.org and the problem will be solved.

**Note**

I have not tried this config with TAP interface so I cannot say if it works or not.